# Converting WPF lib to WinRT lib

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-runtime, portable-class-library

I'm beginner in development for Windows 8 [8.1]. I found [this library](http://wpfmediakit.codeplex.com/) for video processing. But I can't add it to my Windows8App solution. I found some information about Portable Class Library. And now I can't "convert" WPF library to Win8 library. How I can to solve it?

Thanks for reply :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code needs to be converted to a portable class library. It may be impossible due to the operations and libraries used in the original. Given the library you're looking at, which has significant dependencies on WPF rather than just base class library type operations, it's unlikely to be a simple conversion.

Instead, I'd suggest looking for libraries built for WinRt.

Comment: I understand you, thanks. So do you know any library for extracting frames for WinRT?

Comment: I've not tried this, but it might get you started I the right direction: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/windows-8-metro-style-app-development-using-winrt-from-c